# Apollo Client: Component doesn't render after cache update (reactive variables)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Seen similar issues here, but couldn't wrap my mind around those. I'm new to functional components and Apollo Client, and, after reading the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/), created a component that should render a list of items, then (upon adding), update the cache and read from it, rendering the component again. The result is different, though, and I can't understand why the component is not rendering. Apollo Client and reactive variables are used.

Here's my `cache.js`:

```
import { InMemoryCache, makeVar } from "@apollo/client";

export const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: (object) => object.key,
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        items: {
          read() {
            return itemsVar();
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export const itemsVar = makeVar([]);

export default cache;
```

Then, I have the following component:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { useQuery, useReactiveVar, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import GET_ALL_ACTIVE_ITEMS from "../../queries/Item";
import CREATE_ITEM from "../../mutations/Item";

import { itemsVar } from "../../cache";

//Components
import Item from "./Item";

const ItemContainer = () => {
  // this gets the list of items upon component loading
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_ACTIVE_ITEMS);

  // Input to create the new Item
  const [itemInput, setItemInput] = useState({
    title: "",
  });

  const [createItem] = useMutation(CREATE_ITEM);

  const onAddItemClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createItem({
      variables: {
        itemInput: itemInput,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      // Gets the result of the created Item and adds to cached
      let resArray = [...res.data.itemInput];
      itemsVar([...itemsVar().getAllActiveItems, resArray]);
    });
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setItemInput({ ...itemInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  // Sets the cache reactive variable to the data from the backend
  itemsVar(data);
  const items = useReactiveVar(itemsVar);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div onClick={onAddItemClick} className="primary-button">
          Add item
        </div>
           <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            value={itemInput.title}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
      </div>
      {items && items.getAllActiveItems.length === 0 ? (
        <p>No items</p>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          {items &&
            items.getAllActiveItems.map(({ _id, title }) => (
              <Item key={_id} title={title} />
            ))}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemContainer;
```

This components properly renders the items on loading. Now, even though it creates a new item, it doesn't refresh the component (I assume the cache is not updated too, though not sure).

Get all items query:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_ALL_ACTIVE_ITEMS = gql`
  query getAllActiveItems() {
    getAllActiveItems() {
      _id
      title
    }
  }
`;

export default GET_ALL_ACTIVE_ITEMS;
```

Create item query, it creates an item and returns it as an array:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const CREATE_ITEM = gql`
  mutation createItem($itemInput: CreateItemInput!) {
    createItem(itemInput: $itemInput) {
      _id
      title
    }
  }
`;

export default CREATE_ITEM;
```

Can you help me understand what am I missing here?

Comment: 'cache update after mutation' - read docs

Comment: @xadm is it the same with reactive variables, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are NOT specifying if you want to update the cache or not in useMutation hook.

The useMutation hook accepts options as well, like this:-

```
function useMutation<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>(
  mutation: DocumentNode,
  options?: MutationHookOptions<TData, TVariables>,
): MutationTuple<TData, TVariables> {}
```

> So, if you want to update the cache after a mutation occurs, use

```
const [createItem] = useMutation(CREATE_ITEM,{update: updateCache});



const updateCache = (cache, {data}) => {
    
    // Fetch from the cache
    const existingItems = cache.readQuery({
      query: GET_ALL_ACTIVE_ITEMS
    });
    // Add to the cache
    const newItem = ....
    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_ALL_ACTIVE_ITEMS,
      data: {items: [newItem, ...existingItems]}
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks! And updateCache in my case would be the reactive variable itself?

Comment: You need to read and write the cache, I have updated the answer. @Ruham